# RecyclerView ItemAnimator animation not fired when calling notifyItemInserted() in onActivityResult

Tags: java, android, animation, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to update my RecyclerView at `onActivityResult`, but the animation of ItemAnimator doesn't work.

However, if I post delayed this update for a second, the animation works.

Is there a better workaround with this problem?

Comment: We have the same problem, did you solve it? Haha...